# Convert a float[] to a double[] inside a HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hashmap

I declared `LinkedHashMap<String, float[]>` and now I want to convert `float[]` values into `double[][]`. I am using following code.

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, float[]> fData;
    double data[][] = null;

    Iterator<String> iter = fData.keySet().iterator();
    int i = 0;

    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        faName = iter.next();
        tValue = fData.get(faName);
        //data = new double[fData.size()][tValue.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < tValue.length; j++) {
            data[i][j] = tValue[j];
        }
        i++;

    }
```

When I try to print data `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));` it doesn't show the data :(

I tried to debug my code and i figured out that I have to initialize data outside the
while loop but then I don't know the array dimensions :(

How to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: What is tValue?  It seems to be the key to your thinking, but there's no hint about its size or where it comes from.

Comment: If you want to get out of the debugging business here, consider using guava's ArrayListMultimap instead: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, float[]> fData;
double data[][] = new double[fData.size()][];
int i = 0;

for( String key in fData.keys() ) {
    float[] tValue = fData.get(key);
    data[i] = new double[ tValue.length ];
    for (int j = 0; j < tValue.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = tValue[j];
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that there are two steps here that you are trying to conflate into one.  First, you want to create an array of arrays large enough to hold all of the individual arrays:

```
double[][] data = new double[fData.size()][];
```

Next, you'll want to iterate over all the entries, building an array large enough to hold the value:

```
double[][] data = new double[fData.size()][];

int index = 0;
for (float[] entry: fData.values()) {
    /* ... */
    ++index;
}
```

At each of these loop iterations, you'll want to allocate an array to hold all of the floats:

```
double[][] data = new double[fData.size()][];

int index = 0;
for (float[] entry: fData.values()) {
    data[index] = new double[entry.length];

    /* ... */

    ++index;
}
```

And finally, you'll want to copy the data in:

```
double[][] data = new double[fData.size()][];

int index = 0;
for (float[] entry: fData.values()) {
    data[index] = new double[entry.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; ++i)
        data[index][i] = entry[i];

    ++index;
}
```

And you should be golden!

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
double data[][] = new double[fData.size()][];
```

Then later in the loop, you need:

```
data[i] = new double[tValue.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double data[][] = new data[fData.size()][];

data[i] = new double[tValue.length];
```